# Поиск транзитных точек в маршруте

Tags: карты

Есть город А и город Б. Нужно найти между ними маршрут и список городов по пути.

Например, по пути из Киева в Одессу, в списке будут Умань и Белая Церковь.
Для поиска оптимального пути между городами есть множество сервисов, но ни один из них не дает транзитных городов.

Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Уточнение. У вас есть свой собственный список городов и ваша программа должна уметь строить путь между заданными городами, включая в путь транзитные города, или у вас ничего нет и вы хотели бы узнать о сервисе, к которому могла бы с такой задачей обращаться ваша программа и получать ответ?

Comment: @ВладСивирин На данный момент собственного списка нет. Хотелось бы, конечно, пользоваться внешним апи, но готов рассмотреть вариант добавления в базу каталога городов

Comment: По поводу api не могу ничего подсказать, к сожалению. Но мне думается, что api, удовлетворяющая вашим запросам есть. Если готовы добавлять города в базу, то вы можете эффективно искать между ними расстояние и полностью восстанавливать маршрут с помощью Алгоритма Дейкстры. Почитать теорию можно [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B), а хорошая реализация [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dijkstra). Но это, конечно, вариант так себе, если я правильно уловил масштаб ваших целей.